# lftp for sftp is not working; stuck on `ls' at 0 [Connecting...]

Tags: sftp, lftp

I am having an issue with lftp where it gets stuck on

```
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

for an SFTP connection.

Versions:

- Linux 3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 14:55:32 EST 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- LFTP | Version 4.4.8

Here how I am running it:

```shellsession
user@server:~$ lftp -d
lftp :~> open -u Uname,Passwd -p 22 sftp://test.host.com
lftp Uname@test.host.com:~> ls
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l Uname -p 22 test.host.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Password authentication
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

I tried using the various `lftp` `set` commands with no luck.

I then tried connecting using the `sftp` client on Linux and it works.

```shellsession
user@server:~$ sftp -oPort=22 Uname@test.host.com
Password authentication
Uname's password
Connected to test.host.com.
sftp> ls
In  Out  Received
sftp>
```

I had already done the host key fingerprint verification and it exists in the `/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Not sure why it is not working when using `lftp`.

Edit 1:

```shellsession
user@server:~$ lftp sftp://test.host.com
lftp test.host.com:~>
```

Edit 2 (using ssh):

```shellsession
user@server:~$ ssh Uname@test.host.com
Password authentication
Uname's password
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Sorry, SFTP Only - pty-req not allowed.
Connection to test.host.com closed.
```

Comment: Does `lftp sftp://test.host.com` connect?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell.

Comment: try `~>login user password` now  We're trying the "normal login" process before trying the daemon method

Comment: @eyoung100 - just tried `login user password` and the result is the same (i.e. stuck on connecting.....)

Comment: I think you may need to redo your RSA keys.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "redo your RSA keys". I am using password-based authentication and not key-based.

Comment: Can you see any logs?  If it's connecting as evidenced by   `lftp sftp://test.host.com` then there's something wromg with the user or password.

Comment: I don't think it is a user/password issue because I can connect fine using the native Linux "sftp" client using the same credentials and can list the remote directories.

Comment: I apologize.  The issue is with the way lftp is configured or reading the user and password.  By connecting manually, we've verified that lftp can connect to SFTP, but something is missing configuration-wise